# Jaxb: Passing parameter to @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I am creating soap webservice using: Spring Boot / JAX-WS (CXF)
I want to encrypt one field. I am using XmlJavaTypeAdapter for this.
For example:

```
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CypherStringAdapter.class)
   private String cryptedField;
```

The CypherStringAdapter class:

```
package fr.hop.meta4;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;    
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;    
import fr.hop.aes.AESEncryptor;

public class CypherStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Value("${cypher.key}") 
    private String key;

    private AESEncryptor cypher;

    public CypherStringAdapter() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {    
        cypher = new AESEncryptor(key);        
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {

        if (v != null)
            return cypher.encrypt(v);

        return null; 
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if (v != null)
              return cypher.decrypt(v);

        return null;        
    }
}
```

I want to externalize the key value. I am try with @value annotation but it's not working (always null value). How i could achieve to send key to XmlJavaTypeAdapter ?

Regards

Comment: Interesting scenario, not only because of the encryption, but because the unmarshaling of a parameter can be dependent on one or  more other parameters.

Comment: Were you able to pass the parameter to `JaxB XMLAdapter`? I am also looking do something like that where I need to pass a class parameter to `XMLAdapter` and access its Getter methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312205/is-there-a-way-to-pass-class-as-a-parameter-to-the-jaxb-xmladapter-or-access-get

Answer (score 0):

I think XmlJavaTypeAdapter is not a good place for encryption. I change my code to put encryption in my object creation, it make more sense, more easy to implement and it works.

Regards